# raster::intersect not producing expected results

Tags: raster, r

I am having trouble with R's `raster::intersect` method. I give `intersect` a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and `SpatialPoints` as documented in the [`raster` reference manual (p. 111)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf). The result acts like it ignores second parameter. My code follows.

Make spatial points, note `pcts_10_sp` is a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

```
temp_coords <- coordinates(pcts_10_sp) 
temp_crs <- crs(pcts_10_sp)
sp2010 <-SpatialPoints(temp_coords , proj4string=temp_crs )
summary(sp2010)
```

Results of `SpatialPointsDataFrame` summary

```
Object of class SpatialPoints
Coordinates:
                min       max
coords.x1 -97.03242 -96.52624
coords.x2  32.55765  32.98299
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string : [+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27+ellps=clrk66+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat]
Number of points: 694
```

Read polygon shapefile and project

```
pcts_12_sp <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn="Precinct12.shp", layer="Precinct12", verbose = TRUE) 
pcts_12_sp <- sp::spTransform(pcts_12_sp, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
summary(pcts_12_sp)
```

Results of `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` summary

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min      max
x -97.03810 -96.5166
y  32.54508  32.9892
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +ellps=clrk66
+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat]
Data attributes:
    2012_PCT         LD     
 1000   :  1   100    : 72  
 1001   :  1   114    : 68  
 1002   :  1   103    : 66  
 1003   :  1   108    : 66  
 1004   :  1   109    : 61  
 1005   :  1   105    : 56  
 (Other):768   (Other):385
```

Run `raster:intersect` function

```
RasterShp <- raster::intersect(pcts_12_sp, sp2010)
summary(RasterShp)
```

Results of `intersect` summary

```
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min      max
x -97.03810 -96.5166
y  32.54508  32.9892
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +ellps=clrk66
+nadgrids=@conus,@alaska,@ntv2_0.gsb,@ntv1_can.dat]
Data attributes:
    2012_PCT         LD     
 1000   :  1   114    : 57  
 1001   :  1   100    : 55  
 1003   :  1   109    : 52  
 1004   :  1   108    : 49  
 1005   :  1   103    : 46  
 1006   :  1   111    : 45  
 (Other):610   (Other):312
```

The barebones plot of polygons without any points.

```
plot(RasterShp)
```

[image: Plot result]

Comment: What are you expecting and where do you think the function is going wrong. Since we do not have access to your data (polygon) it is difficult to troubleshoot. In this case of intersect your points would receive the polygon attributes but I do not think that the polygons would be effected. For this you would have do use sp::over.

Comment: If you `raster::intersect` polygons with points it will actually intersect the polygon with the *extent* of the points, i.e. `intersect(poly, pts)` is the same as `intersect(poly, extent(pts))`. Looking at the extent of your objects, it appears the points have a slightly smaller extent than the polygons, so I would expect the polygons to be trimmed at the edges. I suspect you're trying to get the subset of polygons that contain a point, in which case you want overlays from the `sp` package. There's a great [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf) on this.